# window.open opens multiple tabs instead of one in google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, dynamic, window

I have created a dyanmic input field with search button.At first only on tab is opened when i click on Button. But after saving if I click on it again then it opens multiple tabs for the same url.
No of tabs is equal to the no of dyanmic input field created and this happens only in google chorme.

```
<button type="button" id='btn[]' name="btn" class='btn btn-default' ><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>

<script>

      $(document).on('click', '[id^=btn]', function(f){
      f.preventDefault()
      console.log('vendor side');
      console.log(this.id);
      window.inputid = $(this).closest("tr").find("td input").attr("id");
      console.log(window.inputid);
      var myWin = window.open("/vendorlist/", "", "width=500,height=500");
  });

  </script>
```

How can I stop window.open to open multiple tabs after dyanmic fields are created.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you click again it will open a new tab.
Just remove the listener with $(document).off if you don't want to listen to clicks event anymore.

```
<script>
    let listener = (f) => {
        f.preventDefault()
        console.log('vendor side');
        console.log(this.id);
        window.inputid = $(this).closest("tr").find("td input").attr("id");
        console.log(window.inputid);
        $(document).off('click', '[id^=btn]', listener);
        var myWin = window.open("/vendorlist/", "", "width=500,height=500");
    }
    $(document).on('click', '[id^=btn]', listener);
</script>
```

the main issue is that the user will not understand why the button is not working, so you will perhaps need to grey-out the button and add an informative title.

Comment: i want that only one tab opens when i click button.I check the same code in internet explorer and it is working fine but in google chorme it open multiple tabs instead of one.

Comment: well i checked your code and if i click only once, there is only one tab that opens. perhaps there is another window.open somewhere else in your code.

Comment: actually this is a dynamic field. First time it works fine when i click it. But after saving when i try to modify it or add new dyanmic field then it opens multiple times .

Comment: perhaps try to be more specific in your selectors, perhaps multiple listeners are on the same buttons